# Пользователь добавляется, но не удаляется. Hibernate, PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, entity, dao

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело может быть. Запросы вроде правильные, но метод add отрабатывает нормально, добавляя пользователя в БД, с запросом в консоли. А delete в холостую отрабатывает без запроса и соответственно не удаляет пользователя из БД.

**Конфиг:**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bookstore</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Сервисы:**

```
@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(user);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Override
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    Session session;
    session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(user);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

**Util**

```
import entity.Book;
import entity.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateSessionFactoryUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateSessionFactoryUtil() {}

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Book.class);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Исключение!" + e);
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

[image: ADD]

[image: DELETE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы производить удаление объектов, необходимо связать экземпляр класса с записью в БД. Hibernate необходимо знать, какую конкретную запись необходимо удалить. Можно получить объект следующим образом:

```
User user = session.load(User.class, 1L)
```

Или же:

```
User user = session.get(User.class, 1L)
```

Таким образом можно получить *PERSISTENT* объект, который можно далее удалять вызовом метода `session.delete(user)`

Либо же удалять *TRANSIENT* объект, заранее установив значение первичного ключа `user_id`:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(1L);
session.delete(user);
```

Подробнее прочитать про состояния объектов в Hibernate можно в документации.

[Описание для Hibernate 3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview)

[Описание для Hibernate 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc)

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как удалять - нужно сначала создать юзера и добавить в БД. Удалять-то нечего... В качестве PK (Primary Key) что используется ? не является ли он null на момент удаления?